# Preventing Segue Failure

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to use shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier to validate whether or not my segue will be performed or not. The problem is the segue is performing first, then checking shouldPerformSegue. In my application, this only occurs during the initial loading of my view controller but successfully works on proceeding loads.

```
- (BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"gameplay"]) {
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"preventSegue"] == YES) {

            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: "The problem is the segue is performing first, then checking shouldPerformSegue" That is not true. You need to describe better what is happening.

Comment: Are you calling performSegue? Because if you are, it will not call shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier.

Comment: Yes I am calling perform segue. What should I use instead Mike?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I was calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` along with `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`. `shouldPerformSegue` was not called because `performSegueWithIdentifier` was called first.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have connected a segue directly from a UIButton/UITableViewCell/UIBarButton to the next view controller. Please remove that segue and then create a new segue from the source view controller to the destination view controller. You can check if you done correctly or not. If you select the segue, the whole view controller gets highlighted. Once done, give that segue a name in the attributes inspector and on that button tap, write `performSegueWithIdentifier`.Your `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` will work as expected.